# SCNuFAST16 PRIuFAST16 warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format

Tags: c

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:10: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format
test.c:10: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format
test.c:12: warning: conversion lackstype at end of format
test.c:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 0xa in format
test.c:12: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format
test.c:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 0xa in format
```

gcc test.c -o test

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    uint_fast16_t n_curve,n_pt;

    printf("Please enter new value \n");
    scanf( "% %" SCNuFAST16 SCNuFAST16, &n_curve, &n_pt);

    printf("You enter % % \n" PRIuFAST16 PRIuFAST16, n_curve, n_pt);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `% %` to do?

Answer (score 6):

That's not how you use those format specifiers.  You want:

```
scanf("%"SCNuFAST16" %"SCNuFAST16, &n_curve, &n_pt);
```

and:

```
printf("You enter %"PRIuFAST16" %"PRIuFAST16"\n", n_curve, n_pt);
```